# How to solve this probability Venn diagram question

Tags: probability

[The probability that a randomly selected pet owner does not own a dog is?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F14Uj.png)

my work:

You add up the numbers outside the dog circle then divide by 100. so that would be 32/100=0.32
so the answer is A=0.32 because a random probability selected pet owner not picking a dog cannot pick in the dog circle so he has to pick outside of the circle which is why the answer is A=0.32

Comment: is my answer correct?

Comment: Not owning a dog, means either someone doesn't own any pet or they may own a cat only. So the answer should be $(32+35)/100=0.67$.

Comment: No.  $.32$ is the probability that a randomly selected pet owner owns neither a cat nor a dog.  Which is an entirely different question.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: $P(B^c) = P(\Omega) - P(B). 
P(A) = P(A \setminus B) + P(A \cap B)$